# Why does Visual Studio think my "yield return" method returns a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, yield-return

I've written a method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` using `yield return` like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Row> ConvertExcelToRows(IExcelDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var row = new Row();
        // do some work. No dynamic objects here whatsoever
        yield return row;
    }
}
```

When I consume my method and follow it with LINQ extension methods, Visual Studio shows the return value to be of type `dynamic`:

[image]

Here is the relevant code leading up to the symptom:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);
using (var stream = await DownloadFile(data.docUrl.ToString()))
using (var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream))
{
    var rows = ConvertExcelToRows(excelReader).ToList<Row>();
}
```

The type of `rows` in the screen shot above is `dynamic` when it should be `List<Row>`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

(Please note that `Row` is just a class I wrote up. It's all primitive properties, nothing dynamic)

**KEY UPDATE:** In the process of improving the screenshot above, I've changed the declaration of `excelReader` from `var` to `IExcelDataReader`. **This solved my problem**.

When I changed back to `var`, I saw that the inferred type of `excelReader` is indeed the contagious `dynamic`.

Would still love an explanation of why a dynamic input argument to my method would "infect" the type of the output.

Comment: `dynamic` operates by [some kind of eerie, hellish contagion principle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/11/08/dynamic-contagion-part-two/). Anything that steps in it, or brushes against it, [becomes it](http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/invasion-of-the-body-snatchers-78_5124.jpg). Once you open a portal into the Late Binding Zone, the compiler starts getting skittish and paranoid.

Comment: You need to define _everything_ that is in your code. Show us the type of the `rows` variable, the type of the `excelReader` variable, what your "do some work" code does that's relevant to the return value. Based on the assumptions we can make, it should work fine, but you haven't given us a reason to believe you.

Comment: Something upstream is `dynamic`. You need to find out what.

Comment: To restate what Ed's link is about, if any part of an expression is `dynamic`, the entire expression will be `dynamic`. According to you, `ConvertExcelToRows(excelReader).ToList()` is `dynamic` so any part of that expression may be `dynamic`, likely `excelReader`. If `excelReader` was `dynamic`, then `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream)` must have been `dynamic`. Assuming the method didn't return `dynamic`, it must mean `stream` is dynamic.. you need to follow that chain of variable declarations to see where this `dynamic` is coming from. It won't just come from nowhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dynamic` operates by a [contagion principle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/11/08/dynamic-contagion-part-two/). If anything coming into an expression is `dynamic`, then the compiler can make no guarantees at compile time about what might come out -- so what comes out is considered `dynamic` as well. There's a limit to the static analysis a compiler can do when types may change arbitrarily at runtime.

Therefore, if what's coming out of your expression is `dynamic` and you didn't assign the result to an explicitly `dynamic` variable, then that's because something `dynamic` must have come in. If you didn't give this method call anything explicitly `dynamic`, then something you gave it must have been "infected" elsewhere.

Something upstream, a parameter to a method, the object you called the method on, or a term in an expression, is `dynamic`. You need to find out what.

An obvious candidate is `excelReader`: Where did it come from, and where did *that* object come from? What were the parameters (if any) you gave the method, and where did you get them?

Patient Zero is out there somewhere.

Comment: Spot on. Patient Zero was `data.docUrl.ToString()`. Fixed by changing to `(string)data.docUrl`. Was surprised to learn `ToString()` on `dynamic` is inferred to be `dynamic` and not 'string'.

Comment: `ToString()` on `dynamic` could be absolutely anything. Once an object is `dynamic`, no normal static analysis applies.

Comment: @urig OMG JSON. I'd better keep an eye out for that. So deceptively convenient. So seductively delicious.

Comment: @urig: NO!!!! It's not "fixed" because it's dynamic, it's merely using an explicit cast that's defined on the underlying type. Please stop making assumptions about the code, refer to the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm). You can't just cast any object backed by dynamic to a type if it doesn't actually support it, you just lucked out here.

Comment: @JeffMercado Where do you see me saying "you can cast any object..." etc?

Comment: @urig: Sorry, I just wanted to make sure you understood the implications of the change you made and how you did it. Adding the cast is precisely the fix for that. However the way I read it, it sounded like you thought calls to `ToString()` on dynamic objects could be replaced with a cast. For any other object, it would have had to be `(string)data.docUrl.ToString()`.